# What is the most accurate way to test the computation speed of a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, performance-testing

I need to compare the computation speed of some code, but I'm not sure what the best way to do that is. Is there some kind of built-in timer to do this? And is it possible to get the computation speed in nanoseconds, or do I need to deal with the milliseconds JavaScript usually works with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the [performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.performance). What you're looking for is probably `Performance.now()`, which will give you microsecond percision.

> The **`Performance.now()`** method returns a [DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp), measured
>   in milliseconds, accurate to one thousandth of a millisecond equal to
>   the number of milliseconds since the [PerformanceTiming.navigationStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming.navigationStart)
>   property and the call to the method [(source).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now)

The example MDN provides is:

```
var t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
```

A function you could use to test the performance of a specific short piece of code multiple times, you could use the following:

```
/**
 * Finds the performance for a given function
 * function fn the function to be executed
 * int n the amount of times to repeat
 * return array [time elapsed for n iterations, average execution frequency (executions per second)]
 */
function getPerf(fn, n) {
  var t0, t1;
  t0 = performance.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fn(i)
  }
  t1 = performance.now();
  return [t1 - t0, repeat * 1000 / (t1 - t0)];
}
```

Which returns the amount of time a single execution of `fn(i)` takes in milliseconds, and the frequency of execution (executions per second). The higher the `n` value, the more precision this has, but the longer it takes to test. The argument `i` can be included in the function to be tested, which contains the current iteration of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for `console.time`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console?&redirectslug=DOM%2Fconsole#Timers.

Comment: This is still in milliseconds, but this looks as much of a built-in debugging function as it would get, so I guess I'll have to deal with the milliseconds and just run the loop for a bit more iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Developer Tools Script Profiler of Internet explorer. I am sure there is a similar tool for Chrome and Firefox too. It will give you in milliseconds. But if the time taken is less than a millisecond then I think it will show in nanoseconds too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the profiling function built-into browser:

- https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699341(v=vs.85).aspx

They are rich-feature and can be used out of the box without writing a single line of code

Answer (score 0):

You should use [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) to get statistically significant results. Due to the various JIT systems involved in browsers, performance results can vary a lot, so jsPerf or the Benchmarking.js library it uses will run your code as many times as it needs to get good results. But note that if a function is running in just a few nanoseconds worrying about its performance is almost always unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

An additional tool is https://github.com/anywhichway/benchtest which just re-uses Mocha unit tests.