# Any speed advantage in JavaScript ES6 const instead of var/let

Tags: javascript, constants, var, let, ecmascript-6

Will there be any speed advantage in using the ES6 "let" or "const" declarations instead the old faithful var?

Comment: I don't think `let` can make anything simpler for the compiler.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, the other question isn't about speed. But I'm not sure SO is the right place for this question either, as the implementations are still in work

Comment: @Richard i suggest making some benchmarking so you can tell it on your own

Comment: Using `let` and `const` in common scope?

Comment: Babel transpiles `let` statements to uniquely-named `var`s anyway, so there's no difference in speed when running Babel-transpiled code (unless you consider that vars of the same name would mean fewer variables in memory).

Comment: I modified the code here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467642/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-let-and-var ) to include a test for `const`, and found that `const` is actually noticeably slower than the other options.