# Are "let x = 0; x += 1" and "let x = 0; x = x + 1" semantically different?

Tags: javascript, performance

Consider the following javascript snippets:

```
let x = 0;
x += 1;
```

and

```
let x = 0;
x = x + 1;
```

Is there any meaningful differences between these two snippets?  The reason I ask is because the first example prevents Chrome from optimizing the function containing it, while the second example doesn't.  [This benchmark](https://jsperf.com/let-compound-assignment) illustrates the performance differences over many iterations.

As for my original question, I wonder if there is any semantic difference because if there isn't, I would like to know why Chrome wouldn't just de-sugar the compound assignment to the `x = x + 1` form.

Comment: Your benchmark doesn't show much. Most of the examples there are never read back (or passed), so the compiler can optimize out the majority of your tests. `x++` especially can be discarded since the compiler can trivially prove you do nothing with it.

Comment: All samples are exactly equal in terms of speed in on machine. (Chrome 56.0.2902 on Windows). 3% maximum difference, but most cases less than 1% from  each other.

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467642/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-let-and-var

Comment: This applies to Chrome 54 which is the current stable version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the standard - they are semantically equivalent.

Relevant part of the [runtime semantics](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

5. Let `op` be the `@` where `AssignmentOperator` is `@=`.
6. Let `r` be the result of applying op to `lval` and `rval` as if evaluating the expression `lval` op `rval`.
7. Perform ? `PutValue(lref, r)`.

> Is there any meaningful differences between these two snippets?

There should not be any observable difference between those.

> As for my original question, I wonder if there is any semantic difference because if there isn't, I would like to know why Chrome wouldn't just de-sugar the compound assignment to the x = x + 1 form.

Optimisation is a complicated subject. `let` was introduced (relatively) recently and is not optimised as well as `var` yet.