# Where to use `var` and where `let` in javascript? (NOT asking difference)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

I have read my blog about the var and let. What I see is this.

> var is a function or global scope variable depend on where it is defined.

where

> let is block scope variable

So in lots of articles, I see they recommend to use let instead of var. I understand that because it eliminated the conflict of the scope of a variable.

So I want to ask where to use let and where to use var? If possible please provide any relevant link for that. If I go with recommendation than I have to use let everywhere.

What I understand is this.

`let` should be used in for loop as it creates its own lexical scope.

```
for(let i =0;i<5;i++){
  setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(i);  
  },100);
}
```

So in this case because of let, we will able to print 0,1,2,3,4, but if we have used var it would have print 5 time 5.

Also, I want to know your suggestion on what should be used in function scope and global scope?

let say, I have file index.js

```
var first = 1; // what should be used here and why

function function1(){
  var first = 1;  // what should be use here and why `let or var`
  var first1 = 2; // what should be use here and why `let or var`
  for(let i=0;i<2;i++){
    console.log(i);
  }
```

Also, I fill let is more than a variable, I create its own lexical scope, there would be more manipulation under the hood like creating IIFE sort of thing.

What I understand is that we should use function and global scope as `var` and let as only block scope? Please provide any recommended link which describes what is better where and why?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check [This Article](https://medium.com/@pandeysoni/when-should-use-const-and-let-instead-of-var-in-javascript-ec2c3d7e5ca6)

Comment: No this article don't describe the question . Where to use var and where let no description .

Comment: potential of duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav

Comment: i3lai3la please read the question . I am not asking difference . I know the difference . I want to know where to use what.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)

Comment: @Himanshusharma you use it whenever you need it. If you're in a fully ES6+ environment, there is very little reason to ever use `var` (can't actually think of any). If you're not, then you can use it because you can't use `let` (or don't want to transpile or whatever).

Comment: @vlaz you means that we such not use var in es6+ environment . And there is no case to use var .

Comment: I certainly can't think of any good reason to use `var`. I can only think of a bad reason - declaring `var myVar` further down in the code and using it earlier. I think that's not really a good reason, though, since you can move the declaration.

Comment: One reason to use *var* is backward compatibility. The primary reasons to use *let* are for debugging and linting. Otherwise, there's no real difference (other than the [*temporal dead zone*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198849/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone), but avoiding that with *var* is not considered a good idea anyway). Block scope vs execution context scope are really not particularly powerful reasons either way.

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly right to only use `let` these days.

In almost all situations, `let` is a better or at least equivalent to `var` considering that leaky declarations make you write error prone code. **Avoid using var.**

Look at this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  document.getElementById('my-element' + i)
    .addEventListener('click', function() { alert(i) })
}
```

contrary to this code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  document.getElementById('my-element' + i)
    .addEventListener('click', function() { alert(i) })
}
```

The first one makes a closure which catches `i`, defined by `var`, while the other one makes `i` different values. The first example makes every callback alert 6, since they are all pointing to the same object. However, the `let` in the second example makes a new block scope every time it iterates. This solves a very common pitfall in javascript.

In most situations, if you need to use `var`'s scope to achieve something not available using `let`, it's almost always a sign that's something is wrong.

Also, don't rely on `var`'s variable hoisting. If you are using a variable you didn't declare before, it becomes error prone.

Mostly, try to follow on the style guide you follow. If you don't have a special style guide you follow, try the AirBnB's: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript
The "never use `var` and use `let`" thing is mentioned here: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#variables

Comment: Where "better" needs to be qualified. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Well, i tried :-) Can you check if it's better?(I'm a newbie...)

Comment: Whenever you write "better" you should be able to immediately write "because…". It's a basic requirement for any technical or formal writing. Your "leaky declaration" is highly contrived and even using *let* in this case would be poor form due to the obvious confusion the re-use of *i* is likely to cause.

Answer (score 0):

### `let` and `var`

You should use `var`, when you wan to define a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope. Variables assigned with the `var` keyword have functional scope. The variable isn’t accessible outside of the function.

And, you should use `let` to declare variables that are limited in scope to the block, statement, or expression on which it is used. When used inside a block, `let` limits the variable's scope to that block.

Variables assigned with `let` are very similar to those defined with `var`. The major difference is scope. This has been referenced above. Variables assigned with let have block scope. This means the variable can be seen within that block and any sub-blocks. Variables assigned with `var` have functional scope and ignore block scoping rules. Variables assigned with `let` can not be **redeclared**, they can only be reassigned.

> According to this [article](https://codeburst.io/const-let-and-var-which-and-when-541a2721c18), Only use the `let` keyword when you know that a variable will have a dynamic value. You probably don’t need to use var anymore

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you know the difference between `let` and `var`, and your question is **WHERE TO USE WHICH?**

First of all, if you are seeking for a better performance, [use let](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21467841/8641396) wherever you are able to. However, you have to be aware that some old browsers may not be able to handle the `let`.

Second, I think the best and shortest answer to your question is " use `let` as long as you can, and if you couldn't then use `var`".

If you study the differences between `let` and `var` deeply, you can figure out where you should use `var` instead of `let`, I recommend you to read this [article](https://medium.com/@pandeysoni/when-should-use-const-and-let-instead-of-var-in-javascript-ec2c3d7e5ca6).

Comment: How is `let test; console.log(test)` a problem? It *works* - you don't get any errors. You are allowed to declare a variable and not assign a value to it, it's `undefined` by default.

Comment: `When you need to re-declare your variable, you have to use var because you cannot re-declare the let.` and why would you need to re-declare? The variable would be *already declared*, why would you re-declare it? The `var` keyword doesn't throw an error when you do that but that doesn't mean it's a correct usage.